# Scala child listbuffer returned as parent listbuffer

Tags: scala

I have started working on scala now. And come to a point where I want to use Inheritance correctly.

I am stuck at once place. I have tried to read docs and other information online. but I seems like I am stuck. 
Please look at this and tell me if you have faced this in the past and whether I am doing something really really wrong.

So, this is my method:

```
 def getFacethierarchy): ListBuffer[BaseClass] = {
      val obj: Childclass = new ChildClass(1, "2")
      val list: ListBuffer[ChildClass] = ListBuffer[ChildClass]()
      list += obj
      list
  }


class BaseClass(var id: Int){
}

class ChildClass(id: Int, var name: String) extends BaseClass(id){
}
```

Now scala Is not allowing me to return a ChildClass instance. 
In Java, this would work (Child is a type of Parent)

I tried to change my method signature to return "Any".
I am not sure what I am going wrong with. 
Please help, if possible.

update:
To be more specific to what I am doing, I have updated the code snippet.

Comment: What is the compiler saying?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve given that there are syntax errors in your code and you're referencing variables without giving their definitions.

Comment: expression of type BaseClass cannot be converted into ChlidClass

Comment: When you make it syntactically correct (like matching parentheses), this should work in Scala too.

Comment: ok. Let me see if I am doing something wrong syntactically. Will update the thread

Comment: no success! I updated my code in the question

Comment: I guess you think `ListBuffer` is covariant in its type parameter, but it is not: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L45

Comment: sorry for late reply. But I understand what you said there. I tried to use the way you mentioned in your answer. It seems to work for me. 
Thanks. I will mark your answer as correct. 
But this is a good learning from me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that `ListBuffer` is invariant, not covariant (no `+` before `T`). It cannot be covariant. For this reason, the `ListBuffer[ChildClass]` is not a subtype of `ListBuffer[BaseClass]`, even if `ChildClass` is a subtype of `BaseClass`.

You can use existential types (`: ListBuffer[T] forSome {type T <: BaseClass}` (hope I used the correct syntax)), or provide an additional type parameter to the method you want to use (`yourMethod[T <: BaseClass]: ListBuffer[T]`). If you want "MyTypes" (might be, hard to tell without further details): [Scala do not support it.](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6649)

Taking a closer look at your code, you might prefer to return a `List[BaseClass]` instead, which is covariant, so you could write:

```
 def getFacethierarchy: List[BaseClass] = {
      val obj: Chlidclass = new ChildClass(1, "2")
      val list: ListBuffer[ChildClass] = ListBuffer[ChildClass]()
      list += obj
      list.toList
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListBuffer[ChildClass]` is not a subtype of `ListBuffer[BaseClass]` because `ListBuffer` being a mutable data structure, it would break the type-safety.

You want to avoid something like:

```
val l : ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer[Int](1, 2, 3)
val l2 :ListBuffer[Any] = l
l2(0) = 2.54
```

---

What you can do is to simply create a `ListBuffer[BaseClass]`:

```
def getFacethierarchy): ListBuffer[BaseClass] = {
  val obj: Chlidclass = new ChildClass(1, "2")
  ListBuffer[BaseClass](obj)
```

}